# Creating a list in Python using a while loop but including the stop condition in the list

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I'm creating two lists in a while loop, which will stop when the user enters 0. My question is, how do I include 0 in the list?

```
            exit = False       
            a = []
            b = []

            while not exit:
                x = int(input("Enter number A:"))
                y = int(input("Enter number B:"))
                     if x == 0 and y == 0:
                          exit = True
                     else:
                          a.append(x)
                          b.append(y)
  
           print(a)
           print(b)
```

Comment: remove the else?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm really new to Python. Won't that stop the list from continuing until the condition is met? If I do that in VSC, it doesn't print the lists.

Comment: Did you try to move the `append` statements before the `if` clause?

Comment: Actually, you were right, but I added append after the if clause and it worked. Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The problem is, you shouldn't use permitted values as conditions to get out of the for loop.
Do you have to insert the x and y values recursively? You could just give the whole lists as input.

If the answer to my previous question is no:
One way to overcome you're problem could be giving the length of the array first, so the program knows when it has to stop:

```
a = []
b = []
length = int(input("Enter arrays length:"))

for i in range(length):
    a.append(int(input("Enter number A:")))
    b.append(int(input("Enter number B:")))
```